# Commerce: Calling unknown method error on Edit Address screen

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, error-message, plugin-craftcommerce3, addresses

I'm using Commerce 3.4.16, Craft 3.7.51.

I'm able to enter an address as part of checkout, and I can see that address in the CP, but when I go to the edit address screen on the front end, I get this error:

```
Calling unknown method: craft\elements\MatrixBlock::firstName()
...    
in .../templates/shop/_private/address/form.twig
```

The relevant code is:

```
{{ input('text', modelName ~ '[firstName]', model ? model.firstName : '', {
    id: modelName ~ '-firstName',
    class: ''
}) }}
```

I get the error in my custom template, and also when using the default templates.

If I take everything else out of the template, both {{ model }} and {{ modelName }} are defined, so I'm not sure what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

You have a variable called `model` set to a matrix block (as per the error, a matrix block doesn't have a `firstName` field). The `model` needs to be an address model.

Comment: But there is no matrix block. I’m not sure why it thinks it’s a matrix and not an address model. The code is straight from the default templates.

Comment: Figured it out. I was setting an unrelated variable called "address" that was referring to a matrix block in my layout template. That was conflicting with my `model` variable which was also set to "address". Changing the name of my original variable resolved the issue.